# UI not found on flow PAD, VM

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I have a problem running my desktop flow.
I run it with Power Automate Desktop on a VM installed on a remote server.
When I'm not connected to the VM Power Automate can't detect the registered IU and triggers an error.
Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks for your help

I modified my flow and did some research on the internet
I hope some will have the answer so that my flow can work even when I'm not connected to my VM

Answer (score 0):

Look at the license model for power automate, you will need an [unattended licence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/guidance/planning/attended-unattended) for that.